# Devise ldap authenticable does not lookup correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I am trying to get user properties from ldap on rails + devise_ldap_authenticatable
(devise_ldap_authenticatable 0.8.1, rails 3.2.14)

Blow is my configuration

devise.rb

```
config.ldap_logger = true
config.ldap_create_user = true
config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
```

ldap.yml (./config/ldap.yml)

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
 group_base: OU=Employee,OU=Person,DC=TEST,DC=AD
 required_groups:
  - CN=users,OU=Employee,OU=Person,DC=TEST,DC=AD

 require_attribute:
  objectClass: inetOrgPerson
  authorizationRole: postsAdmin

development:
 host: 192.168.1.10
 port: 389
 attribute: CN
 base: OU=Employee,OU=Person,DC=TEST,DC=AD
 ssl: false
```

user.rb

```
devise :ldap_authenticatable, :registerable, revoerable, 
       :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
before_save :get_ldap_email

def get_ldap_email
   self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "mail")
end
```

and my LDAP(AD) status is

```
CN=12345678,OU=Employee,OU=Person,DC=TEST,DC=AD is exist
and it has mail attribute => "12345678@test.com"
```

The Login process was good
But It didn't get any properties

log is ...

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = '12345678'    ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: CN=12345678
LDAP: LDAP search for login: CN=12345678
LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
LDAP: Authorizing user 12345678@test.ad
LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: CN=12345678
LDAP: LDAP search for login: CN=12345678
LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
```

and

```
Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "mail")
#It returns nil
```

Maybe the lookup address is wrong...
(maybe CN=12345678,OU=Employee,OU=Person,DC=TEST,DC=AD is correct)

How can i fix it?
How can i get user properties? (ex: mail ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 def get_ldap_email
  self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail").first
 end

before_save :get_ldap_email
```

admin_user: your correct root dn

admin_password: you correct pw

In devise.rb

config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true

Comment: { [2] pry(#<User>)> Devise::LdapAdapter
NameError: uninitialized constant Devise::LdapAdapter
from (pry):2:in `get_ldap_email'

I think Devise::LdapAdapter is deprecated on 0.8.1 ?

Comment: before_save :get_ldap_email

Comment: I missed typo It was before_save

Comment: self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail").first

Array(mail).first — first in array return mail

Comment: [33] pry(#<User>)> Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail").first
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Maby you should use admin user and admin password for search your user, do from terminal LDAP searh (ldapsearch -h ldaphostname -p 389 -x -b "dc=splunkers,dc=com").

Comment: Okay I see. I will try it

Comment: It returns error like this... 
# search result
search: 2
result: 1 Operations error
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this ope
 ration a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1

# numResponses: 1

Comment: When I try to connect AD by Active Directory Explorer(Windows)... It retuns all users infomation... I think I doesn't need admin.

Comment: Do read this issue http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3

Comment: When I set admin element. LDAP SessionController returns error

Comment: In your ldap.yml file I see error required_gourps instead of required_groups

Comment: I didn't copy&paste. My conf file has correct spells. Thank you for let me know.

Comment: You should have LDAP: Authorizing user CN=12345678@test.ad ,OU=Employee,OU=Person,DC=TEST,DC=AD and try to search your user from terminal.

Comment: I have got auth. ldap -h test.ad -p 389 -x -b "OU=Employee,OU=Person,DC=test,DC=ad", -D "CN=12345678,OU=Eem... " -W It returns LDAP data